# Postgres view -- sum all values where dates are the same

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like the below

```
     project|issue|status   |story_points|sprint |date      |active_sprint
     ===============================================
     FB1    |abc  |In Review|     3      |Backlog|2017-06-05|True 
     FB1    |acc  |In Review|     3      |Backlog|2017-06-05|True
     FB1    |adc  |In Review|     3      |Backlog|2017-06-04|True
     FB2    |xyz  |In Review|     3      |Backlog|2017-06-05|True
```

**Expected results**

```
     open|project|date
     ===============================================
     6   |FB1    |2017-06-05
     3   |FB1    |2017-06-04
     3   |FB2    |2017-06-05
```

I've tried for quite awhile and have looked all over but am still unable to figure this out.  I'm fairly new to postgres as well as views and was hoping to get some help.  I've tried a lot of different variations of what's below but am still unable to get this working.

```
    SELECT
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(story_points),0) AS "Open" from sample_table WHERE project = 'FB1' AND active_sprint='True' AND (status = 'In Review')) as "Open",
    (SELECT 'FB1'::text AS "Project") as "Project",
    (SELECT date as Date) as Date from sample_table WHERE project = 'FB1' group by 3
```

Comment: I might be a little bit confused. cant this just be achieved by 
SELECT SUM(story_points), project, date
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY 2,3

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
select project, date1 , sum(story_points) 
from asd1
group by project, date1
```